# Ethereum Wallet (Mist) not showing ETH balance

Tags: mist, wallets, synchronization

I decided to try out Ethereum and installed Ethereum Wallet for Linux. I created an account and sent some ETH from my Coinbase account. I can see the balance in Etherchain, but my Ethereum Wallet account has a balance of 0.

Ethereum Wallet shows:
2 peers
~1.6mil blocks left
6%

Is this typical of an Ethereum application? Are there better alternatives for Linux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since you haven't synced, you're essentially looking in the past. Once you sync to the block where Coinbase sent your funds, it will appear.

Edit: By better, it depends on what you want to do. If you're just looking to interact with Distributed applications dubbed 'Dapps,' MetaMask is a good alternative (https://metamask.io/). It's found in the google apps store and it can also be used to deploy/test code, like the main clients.

If you're more so looking for an IDE, both Truffle (https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle) and Embark (https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework) are good options.